# Validate user preferences set using Settings.bundle in iOS

Tags: ios, validation, application-settings, settings.bundle

I would like to implement a number (float) user preference using my app's settings.bundle but I need to be able to validate the number entered by the user (i.e. the number must be between a certain range). Is there a way to do that?

Thanks,

Tim